# Voltage reading problem in Arduino mega based 10 cannel battery capacity tester

Tags: arduino-mega, multiplexer

I want to make a 10 channels Arduino mega-based battery capacity tester using 4.7 ohms 10w resistors controlling them with IRFZ44n MOSFETs with respected digital pins. An 8.4V battery powers the Arduino (do not consider the buck converter in the picture). I am debugging my project step by step. When I read voltages of individual batteries by corresponding analog pins without turning On 'MOSFET-Gate pins' then Arduino measures the voltages correctly but when I turn on the gate pins then Arduino measures voltage incorrectly. Meaning if I connect
a battery with an analog pin and a multimeter at the same time and the value is pretty much same. Like 3.70 volt for the multimeter and 3.72 for analog pin but when I turn On the gatepin of the MOSFET then Arduino value is like 3.07V and Multimeter value is 3.48V.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the Circuit Diagram of my project:
[image]

Simple version to understand:
[image]

Code:

```cpp
long readVcc() {
   // Read 1.1V reference against AVcc
   // set the reference to Vcc and the measurement to the internal 1.1V reference
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega32U4__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
   ADMUX = _BV(REFS0) | _BV(MUX4) | _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2) | _BV(MUX1);
#elif defined (__AVR_ATtiny24__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny44__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny84__)
   ADMUX = _BV(MUX5) | _BV(MUX0) ;
#else
   ADMUX = _BV(REFS0) | _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2) | _BV(MUX1);
#endif
   ADCSRB &= ~_BV(MUX5);
   delay(2); // Wait for Vref to settle
   ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC); // Start conversion
   while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA,ADSC)); // measuring

   uint8_t low  = ADCL; // must read ADCL first - it then locks ADCH
   uint8_t high = ADCH; // unlocks both

   long result = (high<<8) | low;

   result = 1125300L / result; // Calculate Vcc (in mV); 1125300 = 1.1*1023*1000   //1126400L internalRefVolt(1.1) * 1023 * 1000; code can more precse by calculating internalRefVolt(1.1)
   return result; // Vcc in millivolts
}

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);
   delay(3000);
   pinMode(22,OUTPUT);//***Mosfet Gate Pins********
   pinMode(23,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(24,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(25,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(26,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(27,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(28,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(29,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(30,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(31,OUTPUT);

   digitalWrite(22,LOW);//***Initially low the Mosfet Gate Pins********
   digitalWrite(23,LOW);
   digitalWrite(24,LOW);
   digitalWrite(25,LOW);
   digitalWrite(26,LOW);
   digitalWrite(27,LOW);
   digitalWrite(28,LOW);
   digitalWrite(29,LOW);
   digitalWrite(30,LOW);
   digitalWrite(31,LOW);
}

/**********************************Void Loop******************************************************/
void loop() {
   float voltRef = readVcc() / 1000.0;

   digitalWrite(22,HIGH);//*** High the Mosfet Gate Pins********
   digitalWrite(23,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(24,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(25,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(26,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(27,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(28,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(29,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(30,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(31,HIGH);

   float volt0 = analogRead(A0)*(voltRef/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt0 = analogRead(A0)*(voltRef/1024);
   /* if(volt0>3.0){
      digitalWrite(22,HIGH); // High = Mosfet ON
      digitalWrite(36,HIGH); // High = LED Turn OFF

      }*/

   float volt1 = analogRead(A1)*(voltRef/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt1 = analogRead(A1)*(voltRef/1024);

   float volt2 = analogRead(A2)*(voltRef/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt2 = analogRead(A2)*(voltRef/1024);

   float volt3 = analogRead(A3)*(voltRef/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt3 = analogRead(A3)*(voltRef/1024);

   float volt4 = analogRead(A4)*(voltRef/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt4 = analogRead(A4)*(voltRef/1024);

   float volt5 = analogRead(A5)*(voltRef/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt5 = analogRead(A5)*(voltRef/1024);

   float volt6 = analogRead(A6)*(voltRef/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt6 = analogRead(A6)*(voltRef/1024);

   float volt7 = analogRead(A7)*(voltRef/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt7 = analogRead(A7)*(voltRef/1024);

   float volt8 = analogRead(A8)*(voltRef/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt8 = analogRead(A8)*(voltRef/1024);

   float volt9 = analogRead(A9)*(4.95/1024);
   delay(10);
   volt9 = analogRead(A9)*(4.95/1024);

   //*****************************************************************************
   Serial.print("B0= ");
   Serial.println(volt0);

   Serial.print("B1= ");
   Serial.println(volt1);

   Serial.print("B2= ");
   Serial.println(volt2);

   Serial.print("B3= ");
   Serial.println(volt3);

   Serial.print("B4= ");
   Serial.println(volt4);

   Serial.print("B5= ");
   Serial.println(volt5);

   Serial.print("B6= ");
   Serial.println(volt6);

   Serial.print("B7= ");
   Serial.println(volt7);

   Serial.print("B8= ");
   Serial.println(volt8);

   Serial.print("B9= ");
   Serial.println(volt9);


   Serial.println("");
   Serial.println("==========================");
   delay(500);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the resistor and the MOSFET? Why do you need it? When you turn on the MOSFET, more than 500mA will flow through the resistor to the ground, of course your battery voltage will drop!

Comment: @hcheung: For estimating battery capacity, the voltage under load is often more relevant that the voltage of the unloaded battery.

Comment: I will make a battery capacity tester for that reason discharge the battery current  using the resistor and measure the capacity

Comment: Yes i agree with you but if i measure the voltage using multimeter and arduino analog pin at the same time in underload why the value is different so much. Example : Arduino read= 3.07v and Multimeter read=3.48V at the same time.

Comment: Where did you connect the negative probe of the multimeter? To the negative terminal of the battery or to the Arduino ground?

Comment: Wow! all the time I used the negative probe of the multimeter with the negative terminal of the battery but now I tested with Arduino ground and it gives me accurate value my question is the battery negative terminal is shorted with Arduino GND but why this different result coming out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was the battery holder default wire, those wires were have high resistance. After changing those wire the problem was solved. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2):

Electric wires have resistance. Most of the time this resistance can be ignored, but this is not always the case. Specifically, if the wire is carrying a large amount of current, the voltage drop across it can be significant.

Consider this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPiCfa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The red wires carry a high current, and experience a significant voltage drop. Wires in black carry almost no current, and are equi-potential. Both voltmeters on the left will measure the same voltage, which is affected by the voltage drops along AB and along DE. The voltmeter on the right measures a lower voltage, because it is also affected by the drops along BC and EF.

In your experiment the problem is compounded by the fact that the ground wire is carrying the current from *all* the batteries. It is therefore responsible of most of the voltage drop you experience.

The takeaway is that you have to make sure the junction points between the current carrying wires and the measurement wires (points B and E for the voltmeters on the left) are as close as possible to the battery. Otherwise your measurement will be biased.

Comment: Love you man!! I am working on this project for 5-6days to find out the problem, I thought I have a problem with the code so I tried to simplify my code to find out where the exact problem coming from but yet don't get any solution. But You actually teach me something that I never knew. Thank you so much, brother. Rally appreciated.

Comment: I solve the problem But now  the problem is when I High digital output pin of the arduino to turn on MOSFET-GatePin, Arduino Digital pin voltage drop from 5v to 3v across the gatePin. These thing happening with 7MOSFET and others 3 working perfectly. I changed mosfet and pulldown resistor but no solution.